# Highcharts and jquery-simple-slider seems to be not working together

Tags: jquery, highcharts, slider

I am using jquery-simple-slider
and also Pie chart from HighCharts for calculating EMI similar as this site - http://emicalculator.net/ . I found to have the code conflicting and seems to be not working. If the highcharts are included the slider doesn't work.
Please check Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzhqvxmk/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when loan amount slider is moved - calculate emi
    $("#la").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {            
            $("#la_value").val(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
            calculateEMI();
        }
    );
    //when rate of interest slider is moved - calculate emi
    $("#roi").bind(
        "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
            $("#roi_value").val(data.value.toFixed(2)); 
            calculateEMI();
        }
    );//when no of months slider is moved - calculate emi
    $("#nm").bind(
        "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
            $("#nm_value").val(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
            calculateEMI();
        }
    );


    function calculateEMI(){
        var loanAmount = $("#la_value").val();
        var numberOfMonths = $("#nm_value").val();
        var rateOfInterest = $("#roi_value").val();

        var monthlyInterestRatio = (rateOfInterest/100)/12;

        var top = Math.pow((1+monthlyInterestRatio),numberOfMonths);
        var bottom = top -1;
        var sp = top / bottom;
        var emi = ((loanAmount * monthlyInterestRatio) * sp); //emi


        var full = numberOfMonths * emi;
        var interest = full - loanAmount; //interest 

        var total_payment = parseFloat(interest) + parseFloat(loanAmount);


        $("#emi").html(Math.round(emi)); //monthly emi              
        $("#tbl_int").html(Math.round(interest)); //total interest field
        $("#totalPayment").html(Math.round(total_payment)); 


        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'EMI Calcualtor'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Amount',
                data: [
                    ['Loan Amount',   eval(loanAmount)],
                    ['Interest',       eval(interest)]        
                ]
            }]
        });

    }

});



<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div class="calculatorcontainer">
        <div class="emicalculatorcontainer">
        <div id="loanformcontainer" class="row">
            <div id="emicalculatordashboard" class="col-sm-8">
            <div id="emicalculatorinnerformwrapper">
                <form id="emicalculatorform" class="">
                <div id="emicalculatorinnerform" class="form-horizontal">



                <div class="car_loan_amount">
                    <div class="form-group lamount">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="loanamount">
                        <strong>Home Loan Amount</strong>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">₹</span>
                        <input id="la_value" class="form-control" type="text" value="200000" name="la_value"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            <input id="la" type="text" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1000,100000" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-highlight="true"style="display: none;" ></input>

                </div> 

                <div class="car_loan_amount">
                    <div class="form-group lamount">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="loanamount">
                        <strong>Interest Rate</strong>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                        <input id="roi_value" class="form-control" type="text" value="7" name="la_value"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <input id="roi" type="text" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1000,100000" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-highlight="true"style="display: none;" ></input>                
                </div> 

                <div class="car_loan_amount">
                    <div class="form-group lamount">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="loanamount">
                        <strong>Loan Tenure</strong>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                        <input id="nm_value" class="form-control" type="text" value="4" name="la_value"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            <input id="nm" type="text" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1000,100000" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-highlight="true"style="display: none;" ></input>

                </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="emipaymentsummary">

                <div id="emiamount">
                <h4><b>Loan EMI</b></h4>
                <p>₹<span id="emi">50,731</span></p>
                </div>
                <div id="emitotalinterest">
                <h4><b>Total Interest Payable</b></h4>
                <p>₹<span id="tbl_int">2,925</span>
                </p>
                </div>
                <div id="emitotalamount" class="column-last">
                <h4><b>Total Payment (Principal + Interest)</b></h4>
                <p>₹<span id="totalPayment">2,02,925</span></p>
                </div>

            </div> 


<div id="container" class="col-md-5" data-highcharts-chart="16" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/ssunils/emicalculator

Comment: Just read the documentation.. [click](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation). In your code you are missing jQuery include. Make sure it's **before** highcharts.

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with the slider code you've pasted. The fiddle works if you load the slider resources separately:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/js/simple-slider.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzhqvxmk/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help Krishtoffer. This is working fine in fiddle. But seems to be not working in my project. The slider range values are not changed and unable to view pie chat

Comment: I am able to view  - TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by adding this line of code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Since I was using older version of jquery.